# How can I purify non-drinkable water that may have had organisms in it?

Tags: health, water-purification

I am currently living in the Galápagos Islands. They have no drinking tap water, and the water they provide is not recommended to drink. I got an acute gastroenteritis from it. Here they told me it is an amoeba but didn't specify which. I've been sick for over a week and I'm desperate about the water situation.

I just want a clear answer on what to do to be able to drink the water.

Is boiling non-drinkable water enough?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because tap water is not related to The Great Outdoors. Still you can search in topics we already discussed here about [purifying water](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-purification) while e.g. hiking. There are good filters for that purpose.

Comment: Travel.SE has some guidance on this sort of thing, but generally the guidance in areas with poor water is to either purify it or drink bottled water, wines and beers.

Comment: How to calculate power for an RV (in the driveway) is in scope but how to purify water on a remote island without potable water is out of scope?  Voting to reopen.

Comment: If you have been sick a week and not holding fluids then that could be life threatening.  Ask other locals want they do.  Boiling should kill biological.  https://www.rei.com/learn/expert-advice/water-treatment-backcountry.html

Comment: @Wills the question mentions the *lack* of tap water. It doesn't ask about tap water.

Comment: Purify your water. Brush your teeth with purified water. Don't eat uncooked vegetables or salads that have been washed in water that hasn't been purified.

Comment: @Paparazzi I didn't say that the RV question is *better* than this one. This is a different topic, so you could open in Meta.

Comment: @ppl As I understand the question it is about purifying tap water because it has some amoeba in it. The OP still wants to be able to safely drink it. So this question for me is not in the scope of TGO. Still we could easily edit it ("I have some dirty water, what should I do so I can drink it?") and are fine. But then, as Charlie Brumbaugh said, it's a duplicate. Overall I vote for close.

Comment: @JamesJenkins, When I read "they have no drinking tap water" I understood it as "they have untreated tap water". I would think it can be a duplicate but since OP mentions "boiling non-drinks water" (water that wont be used for drinking or water that is not suitable for drinking?... not sure) it could expand on the crosscontamination using unpurified water for some purposes. As for the scope wouldnt be easier to just take it as we would treat a "remote cabin/beach hut" kind of situation and just decide if its a duplicate or not?

Comment: [Boiling Untreated Water To Make It Safe To Drink](http://www.survivalgrounds.com/boiling_water.php)

Comment: Im also not sure if OP need for a "clear answer", since the ones already in the site seem pretty clear to me, refers specifically to the amoeba (@Connie, it falls under "protozoans" when you look at tables of various purification systems)